# How to Map Custom domain for my GAE project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, webapp2

I am trying to map my Google App Engine project to a custom domain and I am having issues.  Right now it is available at `xxx.appspot.com` & I am following the directions on the following [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains).  I purchased the domain with Google Domains so it is verified that I am the owner.

When I follow the directions, it seems to just stay in a perpetual loop of "Google-managed, Auto-Renewing".  Any tips? I don't need to do anything with a `cert.pem` or `key.pem` do I?

Here is a screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have now been stuck on this for like a week.  I have, I believe, reviewed all of the relevant SO posts and none have been to any avail

Edited: Per John's comment [image: dns]

Comment: Add your DNS resource records to your question. Most likely you have not correctly configured the records in Google Domains. I wrote an article that shows how to set up a new domain on Google Domains: https://www.jhanley.com/google-domains-purchasing-a-domain-name/

Comment: Thanks John, I just updated my question.  I just updated some of the records, they were blank - that might have been the problem.  I'm not sure if I updated them correctly though.  Especially the cname field.

Comment: It's already working!  Thank you John, I really appreciate your help - such a quick fix... oh well.

Comment: I am not sure what you did with the CNAME. I assume you are masking the real data. Post an answer with your solution (e.g. mention what you forgot to configure).

Comment: Note: you have configured the naked domain (example.com). You probably also want to configure `www` so that www.example.com will also work.

Comment: whoops, yes i had two for my cname.  my screenshot cut off my bottom one which was indeed www example.com.  The other cname (above) was from the https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains.  I guess it's not doing any? Sorry i'm new to this.

Comment: The CNAME should be what App Engine told you to create, not something from a book/article/tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments what you needed to do was set up your new domain on Google Domains correctly. This solution was brought up by John Hanley, and provided an [article](http://jhanley.com/google-domains-purchasing-a-domain-name) of his own to solve this.